# Does Snow Leopard work yet?

Tags: mac, compatibility, software

Hey guys!
  Just wanted to see what your experience on Mac OS X 10.6.x has been like. I've been putting off upgrading because it was unstable with so many audio applications for a while. My concerns, followed by what I know so far:

Compatibility with Reaper:
  No recent complaints on forums.

Compatibility with Pro Tools:
  No problem, right?

Compatibility with all-sorts-a-little-audio-tools I've downloaded (like SPEAR):
  Biggest risk - but that's the nature of the beast

Compatibility with Max/MSP:
  No clear data

Compatibility with Wavelab 7:
  Here's *why* I need to upgrade. Wavelab 7 is only 10.6.x

Compatibility with plug-ins:
  Another crapshoot?

Answer (score 2):

I've had 0 problems so far with PT HD 9, RME Fireface, Euphonix MC, Waves Gold Native, Izotope RX+Spectron, Dolby Media Meter.

I can't get Paulstretch to work... For that matter, when i've used it on my 10.5.8 lately, it's been full of glitchy bad distortion too.

Comment: @Roger, weird... Paulstretch works just fine for me on 10.6.5.

Comment: @Syndicate, nice one! Do you mind if i ask you what link you got it from?

Comment: @Roger, not sure. I think I might have gotten it directly from the creator. I have the installer around here somewhere. Get in touch and I'll post it up on my server for you. You can find my contact info on my website, which is listed in my profile here.

Comment: @Roger I use 10.5.8 and it runs fine. I got it fron this link:
http://music.cornwarning.com/2010/04/06/paulstretch-new-build-for-the-new-decade/

Answer (score 2):

I've got a 17" MBP with an MBox2 and I'm on 10.6.5 and don't really have any problems with any audio apps that aren't due to me running 75+ tracks with a ridiculous amount of plug-ins.

Some of the main apps I'm running:
Reaper (I'm always updated to the latest version), Pro Tools LE 8.1, iZotope RX, Wave Editor, MetaSynth Pro 4.0, Waves Diamond Bundle, NI Komplete 4, Adobe CS4, and an insane amount of Plug-Ins

With Reaper I do occasionally have trouble with the PPC Bridge Plug-Ins, but that's sort of to be expected.

I do get a retarded amount of Kernel Panics. I believe it's mostly because I only powercycle my 17" MacBook Pro every few days and I get the panics with no apps open just when I go to restart. No one else I know gets these Kernel Panics though, so I'm thinking it's how long I wait to powercycle and possibly the drives I have connected to my system.

Comment: @Syndicate, I used to get kernel crashes all the time with a MacBook Pro running Leopard and PT 7.4.  I don't know if there's any correlation there, but at the time I didn't know anyone else who had the problem either.

Answer (score 2):

I installed 10.6 on my Macbook, and had all kinds of sync problems with Logic and Live, and Text Edit. Ffs. BUT, my laptop is... counting my fingers, 4 years old. So, what on earth was I thinking? I bought it with 10.4. It weathered 10.5 just fine. And because I thought that SL was mainly cutting out the PPC cruft, I thought it would optimize my machine! Bah. I went back.

SO, there's your caveat. I'd advise against it on an older machine.

4 years... where does the time fly?

Answer (score 1):

A few issues with Max/MSP. Sometimes when working on very old patches that need updated externals. This doesn't happen often, and it's very easy to get working again.

When working with java I had issues compiling. But now seems fine.

I think that 10.6 has been out so long that you'll have more problems not updating than updating. I would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I still use OSX 10.5.8 and Wavelab 7 LE is working. Of course it could be, that the non-LE versions do need 10.6.x , but that would be very strange.
If you can wait some more months: OSX Lion will be out soon (at least this is what Apple says) which should drop the price for the Snow Leopard update.

Comment: Good to know! Upgrading to Snow Leopard is pretty cheap though. And I want me some Wavelab!!! :-D

Answer (score 1):

10.6.6 on a i5 laptop. No identifiable problems for which to blame the OS with one exception - graphics. Had to revert extensions to "SL graphics update 1.0" (the hard way). Not installing 10.6.7 unless something really breaks here..

Answer (score 1):

I have no problem at all with Snow leopard running on old MacBook plus Logic 9, Waves bundle and some Native Instruments instruments. Handles just fine and no compatibility issues.